# How to generate notification while the app is closed?

Tags: android, android-notifications

i have to give notification at a perticulat time (say 7:00am & 9:00 pm.. daily). The notification should come even if the app is closed. Tried searching this on google but didn't get any proper solution.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13121797/1384010 , details can be found here http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

Comment: Look into AlarmManager