# any option in android to get user response from notification and send back to app

Tags: android, notifications, google-calendar-api

I wanted to know there is any method in android where user tap yes/no in notification status displayed in notification bar. And this response is received by my app?? something like inline reply

Comment: you mean adding buttons in the notifications?

Comment: yes like yes/no options and i want that response in my activity?

Comment: yes you can by using addAction and PendingIntent ...
I will show  you an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example
[Determine addAction click for Android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350998/determine-addaction-click-for-android-notifications)

or this tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: to use buttons in notification we have to use notification manager ri8? if we are using or adding events in calender we will not get user response ri8???

Comment: yes you have to use Notification Manager 
but what you mean with events in calender?

Comment: i mean in my app iam adding events in calendar so that in every 3 months i get notifications(say you have to go for injection). But now i want to know whether user went or not..for that i will ask user and i need yes/no reply. I dont know whether it happens in google calendar...so planning to move to notification manager.

Comment: can i know how to set notification from startdate to end date and every 3months????

Comment: you mean send notification automatically every 3 months (locally) ?

Comment: try AlarmManager like this   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121719/notifications-in-specific-time-every-day-android)