# Android Notification "Good morning every day"

Tags: android, notifications

I want to send notification every day at the same time, saying "Good morning".
I know create notifications for a specific day/hour, but for this case I do not know.

Comment: Do you want to send it from your server? or just to create a notification every day at 8am for example

Comment: Yes, you could write an app for that.

Comment: `... Ideas?` Yes: **Google**.

Comment: @fbwnd
I create every day because I want the application user to receive this notification in the morning

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13121797/7461132) solves the question using `AlarmManager`.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Current.this , NotifyService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisApp.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

Comment: As @Abhi mentioned. use that code. In addition, pay attention to register to boot_completed as the alarm will not work after reboot