# Simplest way to get to `BroadcastReceiver` with `AlarmManager` not working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Suppose I have a `MainActivity.java`, where if I press a button(id=`get_button`), I will go to the `onReceive()` of `NotificationReceiver.java` 2 minutes later :

But I am not going there. As for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517520/how-to-give-notifications-on-android-on-specific-time) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121719/notifications-in-specific-time-every-day-android) and many other resources I googled, This seems to be the right way.

My `MainActivity.java` :

```
package com.example.insanes.chothavandar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.get_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 2);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                am.setRepeating(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                        pendingIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My `NotificationReceiver.java` :

```
package com.example.insanes.chothavandar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Not logging after 2 minutes
        // Am I doing something wrong?
        Log.d("DEBUG-EXISTENSE", "Reached in the broadcastreceiver");
    }
}
```

I have registered the receiver in the manifest:

My `menifest.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.insanes.chothavandar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have a `<receiver>` element in the manifest for `NotificationReceiver`? If so, do you have it in the right spot; i.e., between the `<application>` tags, but not inside any other elements, like `<activity>` or `<service>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to write this code in your manifest file.
ex :

```
android:name="com.example.insanes.chothavandar.NotificationReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.insanes.chothavandar.SHOW_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

If you will go to the onReceive() of NotificationReceiver.java 2 minutes later so, you will use a handler in your class.
ex:

```
 private Handler mStatusHandler = new Handler();
 private Runnable mStatusRunnable;
 private void checkStatus() {
        mStatusRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Hear right your on button click code.
            checkStatus();
        }

    };
    mStatusHandler.postDelayed(mStatusRunnable, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't know about the right way or not , but this can be done via Handler in pretty simple way,

```
int TIME=2000
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // do stuff
            }
        }, TIME);
```

Comment: I was asking for the `BroadcastReciever`

Comment: are you sure you got what i was saying here ??! clearly you didn't read the first sentence of my answer ! how would i know that you are planning to use BroadcastReceiver without receiver or any filters ?! i assumed you did that , and just wanted to call your receiver after sometimes! FYI , the accepted answer also using Handler ,just saying!